# How to wrap python function into timeout

Tags: python-3.x, timeout

I used Python 3.x
I have a bunch of code like that:

```
try:
    .....
except:
    .....
finally:
    .....
```

I want to wrap `code into try` with timeout. If over timeout, my code will come to `finally`.
I find many solutions on the internet like: signal,... but I want to wrap, not create a function timeout? Any have a solution like that?

Comment: You could potentially create a decorator for your function that would act as the timeout, raising an expected Exception that will trigger your `finally` block. Though, that is essentially the same as writing a timeout function. If your definition of "wrap" is to emulate a try/except block, I don't think you'll find such a solution because that is akin to asking "How do I create a new Python keyword".

Comment: Hi @gallen, thanks you to give me an idea to do this. Can you give me a keyword to `create a decorator`

Comment: The second example (about timing of a function) on [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/) will help understand decorators. There isn't really a keyword for them, but the `@` simple is used when wrapping a function with a decorator.